# nvim with coc and formatting for python

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

I've been trying to move to nvim as my code editor, but I've been having issues with using the code formatting. For now I want to set it up for python and every time I tried to perform a format operation, I get the following error:

```
[coc.nvim]: UnhandledRejection: request error nvim_call_function - Vim:E117: Unknown function: coc#util#echo_line
Error
    at wF.request (/home/andy/.config/nvim/autoload/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:30:34430)
    at wF.call (/home/andy/.config/nvim/autoload/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:33:3671)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/andy/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-python/lib/index.js:123358:39)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Here is my set up:
**nvim**

```
NVIM v0.5.0
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: /usr/bin/gcc-11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNVIM_TS_HAS_SET_MATCH_LIMIT -O2 -g -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=always -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/build/config -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/src -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/build/src/nvim/auto -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/build/include
Compiled by runner@fv-az242-526

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "
/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/build/nvim.AppDir/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

**npm**

```
6.14.15
```

**node**

```
v14.17.6
```

**coc-settings.json**

```
{
  "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["css", "markdown", "javascript", "graphql", "html", "yaml",  "json", "python"],

  // python config
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",

  "snippets.ultisnips.directories":
  [
    "UltiSnips",
    "~/.config/nvim/utils/snips"
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is came from coc-python, but coc-python is deprecated, https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python#coc-python, try coc-pyright or coc-jedi.

Comment: I would recommend coc-jedi over coc-pyright.  coc-pyright displays nonsensical errors